# How do I write an associative array in Arduino?

Tags: arrays, arduino

I would like to create an associative array.  I believe I can benefit of the key/value type of array for simplicity reasons.  For example, I could have key/values:

PH/2.85,
EC/700,
TEMP/72

I have never dealt with arrays in Arduino and have absolutely no idea where to begin.  The project I am working on has three sensors which are a ph, ec, and temp sensors.  They calculate the data then send it to a C# program which listens for the serial data.  The C# application is working great, but I am having trouble figuring out a strategy for storing the sensor data.  Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, keep hashes/associative arrays in C#, where memory is cheap, and out of the Arduino, where it is dear.  Instead, have the Arduino serialize its data in an easy-to-produce format, using plain print statements.  On the C# end, you can use a library, if needed, to deserialize the data.

Simplest might be serialize the data in [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format:

```
2.85,700,72
```

Or you can serialize the data in [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format:

```
{"ph": 2.85, "ec": 700, "temp": 72}
```

Then, on the C# end, use a [json library](http://json.codeplex.com/) to turn this into a hash in one easy step.